# Get Binance USDT trc-20 trades (ETH/USDT)?

Tags: ethereum, binance, tron

I have a route in nodejs project that returns recent trades from public Binance api route - GET /api/v3/trades.

And my current task is - make this route to return trades from TRON network that were completed in Binance (ETH/TETHER USDT).

After some research I have come to the conclusion that isn't possible and trading pairs on Binance are "network-agnostic".

Am I right or could someone explain this to me?

Comment: Binance updating your USDT balance in their system has nothing to do with TRON. It's when you withdraw USDT from binance that it has to create a transaction on one of the networks used by tether, e.g. TRON.

Comment: got it, thanks. If you post this as answer I'll mark it as right.

Comment: I didn't post it as answer because the question seems a tad off-topic for SO. I'm glad my answer was useful to you, now you can safely delete the question. :-P